# MKMapView on UITablViewCell crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to display MKMapView in a last cell of UITableView.

I have a MKMapView in a UITableViewCell When I scroll the UITableViewCell it refreshes MKMapView. and it crashes with **ERROR: MKMapView must be initialized on the main thread.**

What should I do to prevent the MKMapView from reloading when I scroll my scrollview of UITableView ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     [self.view endEditing:YES];
    if (indexPath.row !=[arrExit count]) //If it is not last cell
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BTSTicketsCellIdentifier";

        BTSComparePricesCell *cell = (BTSComparePricesCell *)[tblComparePrices dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BTSComparePricesCell" owner:self options:nil];
            for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[BTSComparePricesCell class]])
                cell = (BTSComparePricesCell *)oneObject;
        }

             if (!isDragging_msg && !isDecliring_msg)
                {
                    [dicImages_msg setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rowDefault.png"] forKey:[[arrExit objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Merchant_Logo"]];
                    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadImage_3:) withObject:indexPath];
                }

        return cell;
    }
    else{ //If it is a last cell

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BTSTicketsCell";

        BTSMapViewCell *cell = (BTSMapViewCell *)[tblComparePrices dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BTSMapViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[BTSMapViewCell class]])
                cell = (BTSMapViewCell *)oneObject;
        }

        CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
        [geocoder geocodeAddressString:[flux objectForKey:@"Venue"]
                     completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error)
         {
             if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
             {
                 CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                 MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];

                 [cell.MapVw addAnnotation:placemark];

                 CLLocationCoordinate2D _venue = placemark.coordinate;

                 [cell.MapVw setCenterCoordinate:_venue];

                 MKCoordinateRegion region = cell.MapVw.region;
                 region.span.longitudeDelta = 1.0;
                 region.span.latitudeDelta = 1.0;
                 [cell.MapVw setRegion:region animated:YES];
             }
         }
         ];
        return cell;
    }

}
```

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: MKMapView should load in main thread only.  are you changing thread?

Comment: No, i wrote only this much of code which i wrote above

Comment: Try this,  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            //Map code

            });

Comment: @karthika: i tried `dispatch_async` but it crashes here only `NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BTSMapViewCell" owner:self options:nil];` control not reaching `dispatch_async..`

Comment: can you please check here, http://www.mediafire.com/?wmx5564wq51twta

Comment: In this project, not getting crash. you solved that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, hope it will work 
 Create a MKMapView Instance with strong reference in your View Controller where you are loading the map in table view. Assign the lat long values to that map view instance. On CellforRowAtIndexpath set the cell.MapVw = mapViewInstance .

Comment: Crashes here only `NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BTSMapViewCell" owner:self options:nil];`

Comment: Are you sure BTSMapViewCell is valid nibname. If you are having a global mapview instace, then it will not reload at every time when you are scrolling and viewing the tableview

Comment: ie,nib array getting empty?

Comment: it crashes here only `NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BTSMapViewCell" owner:self options:nil];` how should i check whether it is getting empty ?

Comment: shows this `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '<MKMapView: 0xf2a59e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); transform = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = (null)> initWithCoder:: MKMapView must be initialized on the main thread.'`

Comment: I am using Custom UITableViewCell and added mapview through xib and connected to outlet.